# pythonic way to do groupby on list of dict (and efficient?)

Tags: python, algorithm

I am struggling to find a convincing pythonic way to do group by on a list of dict, below seems to be having good readability but not necessary the most efficient way: I have to sort first ( the prerequisite for groupby) and then do the group by (another questiona mark here for the how groupby in itertools is implemented..).

One obvious alternative is to use collections.defaultdict but I will have to do a lot of list.append (and less pythonic?). which one you guy think it a better option? or there is other better way to do group by? thanks

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter

data = [ {'x':1, 'y':1},
         {'x':2, 'y':2},
         {'x':3, 'y':2},
         {'x':4, 'y':1}, ]

sortedData = sorted(data, key=itemgetter('y'))

for y, d in groupby( sortedData, itemgetter('y')):
    print y, list(d)

1 [{'y': 1, 'x': 1}, {'y': 1, 'x': 4}]
2 [{'y': 2, 'x': 2}, {'y': 2, 'x': 3}]
```

Comment: Looks good to me. For implementation, just see the itertools sources, which are available within your Python distribution :)

Comment: Why do `list.append`, when you can `yield`, or equivalently, use list comprehensions?

Comment: Tinctorius, could you please post some example code? for yield or list comprehensions to make this work better?

Comment: Something like `[y, list(d) for y, d in groupby(sortedData, itemgetter('y'))]` (modulo correct syntax, of course)?

Comment: emmm, I actually mean there will be a lot of list.append when we use defaultdict to achieve the same 'group by' functionality.. e.g.

dataByY = defaultdict(list)
for d in data:
  dataByY[d['y']].append( d )

this is more straightforward, but looks like less pythonic, and not sure if list.append is expensive

Answer (score 1):

as you already know `defaultdict` is one alternative. I am not sure about the "pythonicness", but it seems to be about twice as fast(as you asked about efficiency):

```
from collections import defaultdict
def f(l):
    d = defaultdict(list)
    for i in data: 
        d[i.get('y')].append(i)
    return d

%timeit f(data)
100000 loops, best of 3: 3.7 us per loop

%timeit {y:list(d) for y, d in groupby(sorted(data, key=itemgetter('y')),
                                                        itemgetter('y'))}
100000 loops, best of 3: 8.33 us per loop
```

Answer (score 1):

To group an unordered list, you will need to examine each object in the list, and place it into a group:

```
def groupby(iterable, keyfunc=id):
    result = []
    groups = {}
    for item in iterable:
        key = keyfunc(item)
        group = groups.get(key)
        if group is None:
            groups[key] = group = []
            result.append((key,group))
        group.append(item)
    return result
```